# does the integral converge? $\int_1^\infty \frac{2 + \cos(x)}{x^{3/2} + 3} $

Tags: improper-integrals

I tried to find out if this integral converges and I failed. $$\int_1^\infty \frac{2 + \cos(x)}{x\sqrt{x} + 3} $$ I know that $$ -1 \leq \cos(x) \leq 1, $$  $$ 1 \leq 2 + \cos(x) \leq 3$$
And for $$x \rightarrow \infty, $$ $$ x\sqrt{x} + 3 \rightarrow x\sqrt{x}$$ But $\frac{1}{x^{3/2}}\leq \frac{2 + \cos(x)}{x\sqrt{x} + 3}$ and I can't use the sign of converge. And I don't know what to do with it

Comment: You can try finding an upper bound (hint: you already found it for the numerator) and proving it converges and then because the function is nonnegative you can deduce the integral converges from the comparison test.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it converges. You can see this from

$$\int_{1}^{\infty} \frac{2+\cos(x)}{x\sqrt{x}+3}dx \le \int_{1}^{\infty} \frac{3}{x\sqrt{x}}dx = 3\int_{1}^{\infty} x^{-3/2}dx = \\ = -3\left[\frac{2}{\sqrt{x}}\right]_{x=1}^{x=\infty} = -6\left(\lim_{x\to\infty} \frac{1}{\sqrt{x}} - \frac{1}{\sqrt{1}}\right) = (-6)(-1) = 6$$

Since all terms of $\int_{1}^{\infty} \frac{2+\cos(x)}{x\sqrt{x}+3}dx$ are positive, the integral is bounded between $0$ and $6$, so it's convergent.

Answer (score 1):

As you wrote
$$\int_1^\infty \frac{dx}{x\sqrt{x} + 3}<\int_1^\infty \frac{2 + \cos(x)}{x\sqrt{x} + 3}\,dx <3\int_1^\infty \frac{dx}{x\sqrt{x} + 3}$$ For the convergence, this is more than sufficient.

Now, if you want to have bounds, using $x=3^{2/3} t^2$
$$I=\int_1^\infty \frac{dx}{x\sqrt{x} + 3}=\frac{2}{\sqrt[3]{3}}\int^\infty_{\frac{1}{\sqrt[3]{3}} }\frac t{1+t^3}$$
$$\frac t{1+t^3}=\frac t{(t+1)(t^2-t+1)}=-\frac{1}{3 (t+1)}+\frac{2t-1}{6(t^2-t+1)}+\frac{1}{2 \left(\left(t-\frac{1}{2}\right)^2+\frac{3}{4}\right)}$$ which is simple to integrate.